# Empty strings within a list ignored in web, but not in app

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, list

Web version of SE sites ignore empty strings within a list while rendering. [Test post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286872/339911). Both lists look same:

> [image: web]

But in the iOS-app (android-app too) they look different:

> [image: ios-app]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

---

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed for the iOS app in 1.6.2.1.

It's kind of a weird rule with funky edges.

1. This paragraph has a normal margin below it.

   ```
   Code
   ```

   This paragraph has no margin below it.

   ```
   Code
   ```